# How to require more character in commit comment box

Tags: tortoisegit

When making a commit, i wanted to know if we could require all users to add more than only 3 characters so we dont get commits within GITLAB that are like "..." because the user didnt feel like added a note in.

Comment: Then you get comments like `.............................`. This is a *cultural* problem; do people not see value in the context in commit messages? Do they understand why they're supposed to be written and what they're supposed to contain?

Comment: You can add a `commit-msg` hook to check the entered commit message.

Answer (score 0):

Please use GitLab Push Rules:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/push_rules/push_rules.html

## Push Rule:

### Restrict by commit message

Only commit messages that match this regular expression are allowed to be pushed. Leave empty to allow any commit message. Uses multiline mode, which can be disabled using (?-m).

### Restrict by commit message (negative match)

Only commit messages that do not match this regular expression are allowed to be pushed. Leave empty to allow any commit message. Uses multiline mode, which can be disabled using (?-m).

## How to implement into your organization

You really don't want to check that a commit message does not equal "...".
You usally want to align with your team on a process like "no commit without a (Jira/Bugzilla/Redmine/Kanbanize/etc.) ticket. Commit messages starts with a ticketnumer, e.g. "PRJ-1234: blablabla"

Of course everybody has his/her stupid tasks, where one might be lazy on setting a commit message. But for the 99% important commits, you should talk about the users feelings. Maybe you should get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

In TortoiseGit you can configure a minimum size for the commit message (this is, however, only enforced when using TortoiseGit; cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-dialogs3)

When you store this to the `project` level and commit `/.tgitconfig` this setting will be effective for all TortoiseGit users of the repository.

Comment: @Anthony Please consider to accept this answer if it helped you or leave a comment on what's still missing.